# $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A) \iff d(x, A^c) > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

In $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric $|\cdot|$. I have to show that

$$x\in \text{Int}(A) \iff  d(x,A^{c})>0$$

where $\text{Int}(A)$ is the interior  of $A$. When i suppose that $d(x,A^{c})>0$ I have to show that $x\in \text{Int}(A)$. For this, let  $x\in A$ and I consider $\epsilon = d(x,A^{c})$, and I construct $B_{\epsilon} (x)=${$y\in \Bbb R  :  |x-y|<\epsilon$}. Am I in the right way? and if I am, how i can conclude that?.

When I suppose that $x\in \text{Int}(A)$ so I know that $d(x,A^{c})\geq 0$ so $d(x,A^{c})=0$ or $d(x,A^{c})\gt 0$ but if I consider the case $d(x,A^{c})= 0$ that is $d(x,A^{c})= \sup \{|x-y|$ : $y \notin \Bbb R \}=0$ but I know there exist some $\epsilon >0$ such that  $B_{\epsilon} (x)\subset A$ and i don't know if it follows. I accept any suggestions or comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r=d(x,A^{c}) >0$. Then $B(x,r) \subseteq A$ because if $d(y,x) <r$ but $y \in A^{c}$ then we get the contradiction $r=d(x,A^{c}) \leq d(y,x) <r$.

Now suppose $B(x,r) \subseteq A$. Then $y \in A^{c}$ implies that  $y \notin B(x,r)$ which means $d(y,x) \geq r$. Since this is true for all $y \in A^{c}$ we get $d(x,A^{c}) \geq r$ so $d(x,A^{c})>0$.

Answer (score 0):

We will prove the contrapositive.

For the first part, suppose $x \notin \text{Int}(A)$. Then $x \in \overline{A^c}$ i.e. $d(x, A^c) = 0$. So $d(x, A^c)$ is not strictly greater than $0$.

For the second part. Suppose $d(x, A^c)$ is not strictly greater than $0$. Then this forces $d(x, A^c) = 0$ which implies $x \in \overline{A^c}$ i.e $x \not\in \text{Int}(A)$.